# How can I get past recaptcha with Playwright for node.js/typescript and pnpm?

Tags: recaptcha, playwright, playwright-typescript

I'm trying to submit a form with recaptcha in Playwright using node.js/typescript and pnpm. However, when the form is submitted, I get a recaptcha error message. Is there a way to solve this?

I found and tried https://github.com/xrip/playwright-recaptcha-solver but get errors while trying to add it to my project using pnpm or npm.

Comment: Please share the exact errors and your code, and the site or captcha you're trying to automate as a [mcve]. Without these details, there's basically no way to help. Thanks.